# Javascript filter record by using multiple array

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I have **result** type of object. I want to filter the records from the result obj. I have 3 filters in my form (Search by name, city, email). All filters are multi-select. Now I want to filter my result records by the above filters array.

**User filtered by records using below array**

```
var searchByname = ['john', 'test1'];
var searchByEmail = ['john@gmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com'];
var searchByCity = ['CA', 'LA'];
```

**Actual result object from where the filter should be done**

```
var result = [
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'email': 'john@gmail.com',
        'city': 'CA',
        'phone': 425663313
    },
    {
        'name': 'test1',
        'email': 'test1@gmail.com',
        'city': 'LA',
        'phone': 7418669633
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dyna',
        'email': 'Dyna@gmail.com',
        'city': 'New York',
        'phone': 12345666
    }
]
```

**I tried below solution but it filter only any one filter records**

```
var filteredArray_1 = result.filter(function(itm){
    return searchByname.indexOf(itm.name) > -1;
});
var filteredArray_2 = result.filter(function(itm){
    return searchByEmail.indexOf(itm.email) > -1;
});
var filteredArray_3 = result.filter(function(itm){
    return searchByCity.indexOf(itm.city) > -1;
});
let finalArray = [...filteredArray_1, ...filteredArray_2, ...filteredArray_3];
```

**Expected Output**

```
var result = [
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'email': 'john@gmail.com',
        'city': 'CA',
        'phone': 425663313
    },
    {
        'name': 'test1',
        'email': 'test1@gmail.com',
        'city': 'LA',
        'phone': 7418669633
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter includes results from *any* passing filter and can include results twice.

Instead apply *all* your filters together:

```js
const searchByname = ['john', 'test1'];
const searchByEmail = ['john@gmail.com', 'test1@gmail.com'];
const searchByCity = ['CA', 'LA'];

const result = [
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'email': 'john@gmail.com',
        'city': 'CA',
        'phone': 425663313
    },
    {
        'name': 'test1',
        'email': 'test1@gmail.com',
        'city': 'LA',
        'phone': 7418669633
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dyna',
        'email': 'Dyna@gmail.com',
        'city': 'New York',
        'phone': 12345666
    }, 
    undefined, // Dummy test empty
    { } // Dummy test with no properties
];

const multifiltered = result.
    filter(itm => searchByname.indexOf(itm?.name) > -1).
    filter(itm => searchByEmail.indexOf(itm?.email) > -1).
    filter(itm => searchByCity.indexOf(itm?.city) > -1);
    
console.log('Multiple filters', multifiltered);

// However, your code will be easier to read if you do a single operation...

const filteredAND = result.
    filter(itm => 
        itm &&
        searchByname.indexOf(itm.name) > -1 &&
        searchByEmail.indexOf(itm.email) > -1 &&
        searchByCity.indexOf(itm.city) > -1);
        
console.log('AND filters', filteredAND);

const filteredOR = result.
    filter(itm => 
        itm && (
        searchByname.indexOf(itm.name) > -1 ||
        searchByEmail.indexOf(itm.email) > -1 ||
        searchByCity.indexOf(itm.city) > -1));
        
console.log('OR filters', filteredOR);
```

Comment: Is it giving me result if one of my filter is null?

Comment: @UserPHP No, but its easy to add `item && (...)` around the clause

Comment: I am not getting can add it into the current code

Comment: @UserPHP snippet updated with null checks

Comment: From my 3 filters if only searchByname has value but other two has not any value they both are empty is it works?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question fully.

but you could filter in this manner

```js
var filtered = result.filter(
  (item) =>
    searchByname.includes(item.name) ||
    searchByEmail.includes(item.email) ||
    searchByCity.includes(item.city)
);
```

This would give you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of this based on your requirement,

```
let andFiltered = result.filter(
  (data) =>
    searchByname.includes(data.name) &&
    searchByEmail.includes(data.email) &&
    searchByCity.includes(data.city)
);

console.log(andFiltered);

let orFiltered = result.filter(
  (data) =>
    searchByname.includes(data.name) ||
    searchByEmail.includes(data.email) ||
    searchByCity.includes(data.city)
);

console.log(orFiltered);
```